Remove empty dirctories in Python recursively
I have the following script in Pyth to remove empty directories. This will remove an empty directory with the filepath "a/b/c" no matter how many folders down. The problem is, sometimes if folder "c" is removed because it is empty, folder "b" is in turn empty, but then I have to keep running this code until all the empty folders are truly gone. Is there a way to avoid this problem?
directories = glob.glob(f"{DIR_DOCS}/**/", recursive=True)

for directory in directories:
    if not os.listdir(directory):
        os.rmdir(directory)
        print(f"Removed directory: {directory}")

Example filepath: "data/docs/TX/Fort Worth/2024-11-09/Meeting1/Test" - If Test2 is empty and removed, Meeting1 should be removed, then 2024-11-09.
I saw the answers to a similar question here but none of the solutions work for me.

"but none of the solutions work for me" - please explain.

Try traversing directories in reverse order.

really? os.removedirs(path) suggested in the linked question didn't work? If it didn't work, then your directories are not empty
